# How to print a json string parsed as a php object

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string that I parsed as a PHP object, there are certain values I want to print from the string, how do I print the exact value I need.

I have provided the code below

```
{
  "data":
    {
      "id":123, 
      "name": "abc", 
      "gsm":"1133", 
      "metadata": 
      {
        "cart_id":13243
      }, 
      "customer": 
      {
        "id":123,
        "email": "a@ma.co"
      }
    }
}

json_decode($string);
```

for instance "name": abc, I want to print just abc

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. and once you correct your JSON then `$jsondecodeoutput->data->name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string is not valid, You missing bracket in it.Also string value must contain quotes in json. Your string should be like

```
$string= '{
  "data": {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "abc",
    "gsm": 1133,
    "metadata": {
      "cart_id": 13243
    },
    "customer": {
      "id": 123,
      "email": "a@ma.co"
    }
  }
}';

$response = json_decode($string);
print_r($response->data->name);
die;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON to an array and access the element by key

```
$jArr = json_decode($string, true);
```

Access the elements

```
$jArr['data']['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$string = '{"data":{"id":123}}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($string, true);

echo $jsonObj['data']['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the elements from json decode, like this:

```
$JSON = '{
    "data":{
        "id":123,
        "name": abc,
        "gsm":1133,
        "metadata":{
            "cart_id":13243
        },
        "customer":{
            "id":123,
            "email": "a@ma.co"
        }
    }
}'; //There were three errors, you have to to use ' insted of " for including the JSON string, you missed one '}' and you forgot the "" in the 'email' value under 'customer' section

$object = json_decode($JSON);
echo 'Printing the customer id using an object: '.$object->data->customer->id.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

$array = json_decode($JSON, true);
echo 'Printing the customer id using an array: '.$array['data']['customer']['id'];
```

This code prints:

```
Printing the customer id using an object: 123

Printing the customer id using an array: 123
```